# Нужно из текста получить частотный словарь, програма выводит ключ и значения, но в каждом новом рядке добавляет по новому ключу и значению

Tags: python, словари

```
import collections
text = "These people had a little window at the back of their house from which a splendid garden could be seen, which was full of the most beautiful flowers and herbs. It was, however, surrounded by a high wall, and no one dared to go into it because it belonged to an enchantress, who had great power and was dreaded 
by all the world."
t = text.replace(',', '')
#print(t)
print(max(t.split(), key=len))
print(min(t.split(), key=len))
print(collections.Counter(text.split()).most_common(1))

ma_dict = {}
for word in text.split():
    ma_dict[word] = ma_dict.get(word, 0) + 1
    print(ma_dict)
```

Comment: я потестил Ваш код и он похоже работает как я и ожидаю. Можете привести пример вывода и что там не так?

Comment: {'These': 1}
{'These': 1, 'people': 1}
{'These': 1, 'people': 1, 'had': 1}        
{'These': 1, 'people': 1, 'had': 1, 'a': 1}
{'These': 1, 'people': 1, 'had': 1, 'a': 1, 'little': 1}
{'These': 1, 'people': 1, 'had': 1, 'a': 1, 'little': 1, 'window': 1}
{'These': 1, 'people': 1, 'had': 1, 'a': 1, 'little': 1, 'window': 1, 'at': 1}
{'These': 1, 'people': 1, 'had': 1, 'a': 1, 'little': 1, 'window': 1, 'at': 1, 'the': 1}
{'These': 1, 'people': 1, 'had': 1, 'a': 1, 'little': 1, 'window': 1, 'at': 1, 'the': 1, 'back': 1}

Comment: ну так логично, Вы печатаете содержимое мапы на каждой итеррации. Удалите пробелы перед print в последней строке все будет заметно лучше.

Comment: Спасибо) Может Вы ещё знаете, как сделать словарь со слова с количеством их гласных звуков?

Comment: нет, я не знаю, как этот словарь должен выглядеть.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну так логично, Вы печатаете содержимое мапы на каждой итеррации. Удалите пробелы перед print в последней строке все будет заметно лучше.

```
import collections
text = "These people had a little window at the back of their house from which a splendid garden could be seen, which was full of the most beautiful flowers and herbs. It was, however, surrounded by a high wall, and no one dared to go into it because it belonged to an enchantress, who had great power and was dreaded 
by all the world."
t = text.replace(',', '')
#print(t)
print(max(t.split(), key=len))
print(min(t.split(), key=len))
print(collections.Counter(text.split()).most_common(1))

ma_dict = {}
for word in text.split():
    ma_dict[word] = ma_dict.get(word, 0) + 1

print(ma_dict)
```